# Return last character of each word within a string

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

My problem is as follows.
I need to remove the punctuation within a large string.
I then need to remove and return the last letter of each WORD in the string into either a list or string.

Here is the string I am working with.

```
text = """
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.
Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient python,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
baxa quouq. axa la consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Proin at neque et tellus ultricies consequat. Duis vitae mi commodo, suscipit nunc vel, porta tellus.
In eu volutpat sapien. Mauris dignissim velit eget diam tristique, nec egestas magna maximus.
Pellentesque python, lorem a eleifend vehicula, arcu urna facilisis odio, maximus maximus massa nisl sed sapien.
Quisque nisi nunc, dignissim ut malesuada non, fringilla vitae sem. Nunc turpis quam, rutrum at egestas ut, pretium tincidunt est.
Praesent imperdiet mauris eu felis lobortis vehicula. Sed dictum lorem at rutrum rhoncus. Suspendisse sit amet ex ac eros python cursus.
Duis pretium rutrum lacus, sit amet vulputate ipsum condimentum vel. Vivamus lacus ipsum, python in justo quis,
blandit condimentum velit esed semper posuere leo, elementum tristique leo euismod quis
"""
```

I was successful in removing the punctuation from the string using this code here.

```
def remove(element):
    new = ""
    for i in element:
        if i not in "?.!,:;":
            new += i
    print (new)


remove(text)
```

I was also successful in removing the last letter in each word in the string using this code here.

```
def last_item(item):

    splitter = item.split()

    print([x[:-1] for x in splitter])



last_item(text)
```

I am now stuck on how to RETURN the values I have removed into a new list or string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `return [x[:-1] for x in splitter]` inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.puncuation` with a generator expression to remove punctuation. Then a list comprehension can split on whitespace, and grab the last letter from each word.

```
import string
def clean_string(s):
    return ''.join(i for i in s if i not in string.punctuation)

>>> [word[-1] for word in clean_string(text).strip().split(' ')]
['n', 'o', 'a', 't', 'r', 'n', 'a', 'm', 's', 'e', 's', 't', 's', 's', 't', 'r', 's', 's', 'c', 'm', 's', 's', 'c', 'e', 'u', 'm', 's', 'm', 'a', 't', 'a', 's', 'c', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'l', 't', 'c', 'e', 't', 'u', 'm', 's', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'r', 'r', 's', 'm', 't', 'i', 'm', 's', 'n', 'o', 'a', 't', 'r', 'n', 'a', 'm', 's', 'e', 's', 't', 's', 's', 't', 'r', 's', 's', 'c', 'm', 's', 's', 'c', 'e', 'u', 'm', 's', 'm', 'a', 't', 'a', 's', 'm', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'l', 't', 'c', 'e', 't', 'u', 'm', 's', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'r', 'r', 's', 'i', 'm', 't', 'i', 'm', 'm', 's', 'e', 's', 't', 's', 's', 't', 's', 'r', 's', 's', 'c', 'm', 's', 's', 'c', 'e', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'q', 'a', 'a', 't', 'a', 's', 'm', 'c', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'l', 't', 'c', 'e', 't', 'u', 'm', 's', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'r', 's', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 't', 's', 's', 't', 's', 'e', 'i', 'o', 't', 'c', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'u', 't', 'n', 's', 'm', 't', 't', 'm', 'e', 'c', 's', 'a', 'e', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'u', 'a', 's', 'o', 's', 's', 'a', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'c', 'm', 't', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'e', 'm', 'c', 's', 'm', 'm', 't', 's', 't', 'm', 't', 't', 't', 's', 'u', 's', 's', 'a', 'd', 'm', 'm', 't', 'm', 's', 'e', 't', 't', 'x', 'c', 's', 'n', 's', 'm', 'm', 's', 't', 't', 'e', 'm', 'm', 'l', 's', 's', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'o', 't', 'm', 't', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'o', 'd', 's']
```

Comment: Thanks CoryKramer!
Super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best approach but it works.

```
new = ""

for i in text:
    if i not in "?.!,:;":
        new += i


print new

x = new.split(' ')

new1 = ""
for i in x:
    print i[-1:]
    new1 += i[:-1]
    new1 += ' '

print new1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ''.join([x[-1] for x in splitter]) # as punctuation have been removed as per question.
```